# Yammer embed code double scrollbar

Tags: iframe, yammer

I have embedded the Yammer news feed onto a SharePoint page. It works fine, but recently a second vertical scrollbar appeared. It seems to be part of the iframe. Does anyone know of a way to remove this extra vertical scrollbar?

Here is the image for scroll - bar 
 [image]

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of the second scrollbar? I can't see it my network.

Answer (score 0):

We are also experiencing the same issue. This wasn't a problem prior to December, but it appears there was an update that's included adding overflow-y:scroll to the html tag within the iframe.

It's easy to see the problem from the Yammer Widget configuration page: https://www.yammer.com/widget/configure

As the issue is within the iframe, I believe we have to wait for an update from the Yammer dev team to resolve...

update - here's a screenshot (i'm new and it wont let me comment)
[screenshot of yammer embed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cDEp2.png)

Answer (score 0):

it looks like Yammer fixed the problem! I would check again to see if the issue is resolved

Comment: Yes it looks like it is fixed for the feed, but it still an issue for embedded comments.